# How can i extend header row and summary lines of table?

Tags: xetex, pdftex

I want to extend header row and summary lines of table to page width. Please someone help me with this, i don't know how to do it.

Here is my existing table:
[image: image 1]

The table i want:
[image]

My Code:

```
\begin{longtable}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}\hspace{\tabcolsep}} p{.6\textwidth} l r r r r }
    \hline
    \rowcolor{black}
    \textcolor{white} {POS} &\textcolor{white} {DESCRIPTION} & \textcolor{white} {QTY} & \textcolor{white} {PRICE (\pounds)} & \textcolor{white} {AMOUNT  (\pounds)} \\*
    \hline\hline
    \endhead
}{

    & & & {MWSt \taxval \%} & {\taxes{\arabic{cost}}{\taxval}} \\
    \hline\hline\hline
    & & &  {Summe EUR} & {\addtaxes{\arabic{cost}}{\taxval}} \\
    \end{longtable}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SE! Please show us what you tried so far!

Comment: Since you use `longtable`: Dose your actual table span multiple pages?

Comment: How are the commands `\taxval`, `\addtaxes` and `\taxval` defined? Did you load a package/class that defines these commands? If so, please also add this information to your question.

Answer (score 3):

To adjust the position of the table change `\oddsidemargin -1in`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
\marginparwidth 0pt
\marginparsep 0pt
\oddsidemargin \dimexpr .5in -1in
\textwidth \dimexpr \pdfpagewidth \oddsidemargin -1in 

\begin{table} % 
    \centering
    \caption{Obtained marks.} 
    \begin{tabular}{p{16cm} l l l l }
        \hline Name & Math & Phy & Chem & man \\
        \hline Salah & 80 & 68 & 60 & 57\\
        \hline Muhammed & 72 & 62 & 66 & 63\\
        \hline Ahmad & 75 & 70 & 71 & 69\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}   
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution will as well change the alignment/position of any contents other than the table.

Comment: @leandriis , you can adjust the margin before and after the table.